# Modules using each other's local objects

Tags: module, lua, local

In vanilla Lua 5.2, I have a module that contains:

- Two local functions, A and B: B will always call A, A will sometimes call B and sometimes will call the functions stored in C;
- C: a table (local). It contains tables which contains tables which can contain tables... which will at the end contain functions. These functions *may* call either A or B;
- Then there's the return function, D, which will be returned when my module is loaded using `require`. It will call A.

At the end, it looks quite like this:

```
--don't pay attention to what the functions do:
--I am only writing them down to explain how they interact with each other

local A, B, C

C = {
    ...
    {
        function(a)
            B(a)
         end
    }
    ...
}

A = function(a)
    ...
    if (...) then
        B(a)
    end
    ...
    if (...) then
        C[...]...[...](a)
    end
    ...
end

B = function(a)
    A(a)
end

return function(s) -- we called this one D
    A(s)
end
```

Now, my problem is this: the declaration of C uses its own local variables, metatables and all that stuff, to the point I enclosed its declaration in a `do ... end` block.

It also is - with all those tables inside tables and newlines for each curly brace and indentation and so on - quite long. So I wanted to put it in its own module, but then it couldn't access B.

So, my question is: is there a way to pass B and maybe even A to the file where C is declared while loading it? I mean something like this, if it were possible:

```
--in the original module
local A, B, C

C = require("c", A, B)

...
```

And then, in c.lua:

```
local A, B = select(1, ...), select(2, ...)

C = {
    ...
    {
        function(a)
            B(a)
        end
    }
    ...
}
```

I really have no idea on how to do it.

Is there a way to pass variables from the requiring file to the required file which doesn't involve the variables being inserted in the global namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

main module:

```
local A, B, C

A = function(a)
    ...
    if (...) then
        B(a)
    end
    ...
    if (...) then
        C[...]...[...](a)
    end
    ...
end

B = function(a)
    A(a)
end

C = require("c")(A, B)

return function(s) -- we called this one D
    A(s)
end
```

---

c.lua:

```
local function C_constructor(A, B)
    local C = 
        {
            ...
            {
                function(a)
                    B(a)
                end
            }
            ...
        }
    return C
end

return C_constructor
```

Comment: That's clever, really clever.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass variables from the requiring file to the required file which doesn't involve the variables being inserted in the global namespace?

Not with the default `require` function, but that shouldn't stop you from writing your own `require` function that does this. Obviously this will make the solution specific to your application, so those required files will not function correctly when a standard Lua interpreter (with its `require` function) is used.

Comment: That actually _will_ stop me lol. I'm not writing a standalone application actually, and I will one day traslate the whole codebase to C or C++, so why bother?